# laravel executing a command error: no input file specified

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm executing this in my crontab:

```
php artisan command:foo test
```

Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.24
Content-type: text/html

No input file specified.

How can I write a right path for the artisan file?

Comment: Artisan file is in same directory as you project. So first create new project, then change directory to the root of that project, and then you will be able to use artisan.

Comment: @Alen I'am on a shared hosting, there I have a crontab, how should I get the exact path to my artisan?